# How to create a global object on C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m making a simple CAD application on Unity 3D using C# to configure closets. Right now i have a few scripts and classes and I need to make the closet a global object accessible for every script of the project.

I tried setting the closet class as `static` but, since its modified every time I cant make it that way. Is the first time I work with C# and im kinda lost.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a global, I would recommend creating a GameObject which you can then find in your scripts using GameObject.Find() method.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject cabinet;
    void Start() {
        //find the cabinet object in your scene
        cabinet = GameObject.Find("Cabinet");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only proper way to do it, as a `public static` class, method, or variable is the closest c# has to `global`.

Comment: But if I do it that way i lose all the information of the closet. And its not the way im looking for since my closet object is made of four GameObjects and a few more objects inside, so it has to be a global closet object

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue a while back.  The solution I came up with is simple Create a WorldGameObject in which all objects derive from this in the project hierarchy

Then if you want you can call this code in all classes or create a base class which gets the parent via the root

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//Add this class to your world game object and store your globals here
public class GlobalContext : MonoBehaviour{
}

public class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private GlobalContext world;
    void Start() {
        //find the cabinet object in your scene
        world= transform.root.GetComponent<GlobalContext>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, dont know why but the first time I tried with `static` it came up with some errors but now it worked fine. I can access to this object from anywhere.